# What to resolve. Normal reaction or the weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I solved the question by resolving weight. Answer doesn't come up if I resolve normal reaction $N \cos \theta = mg$. Why so? 
[This is the question.](https://ibb.co/ceEgGG)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because $N\cos\theta\neq mg$. There is non-zero acceleration in the downward direction.